# CsvHelper GetRecords Yielded no results

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, csvhelper

I want to parse large csv into data structures. I created simple dotnet core **console** app to test CsvHelper library.

this is basically the code:

```
var csv = new CsvReader(File.OpenText(filename));
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CardMap>();
var records = csv.GetRecords<Card>();
```

everything works fine, but when I copied same code, with same data structures into dotnet core **mvc** app, using same csv file (from same directory) GetRecords yields no results.

any idea where could be the problem? I have no idea how to debug this, stream going into new CsvReader is fine, file content is read, otherwise its all blackbox.

is there some limitation when using this library in mvc app? I tried to move this code into Program.cs Main(), but no change (I run it from HomeController).

Comment: What are you doing with `records` after this?

Comment: I want to iterate them. problem is records already are empty. when check records value in debug mode, it points to string containing "Yields no records".

Comment: Looks like `OpenText` opens a `UTF-8` encoded text file. Is your file UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: this file is UTF-8. as I said, I use exactly same file in console app and it works fine, problem only happens in mvc app.

Comment: Hey man, I'm having the same problem @aacid how did you solve it?